# How to build fulfillment for context?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Tried to follow the sample code as this

```js
app.intent('intent1', (conv) => {
  const lifespan = 5;
  const contextParameters = {
    color: 'red',
  };
  conv.contexts.set('context1', lifespan, contextParameters);
  // ...
});

app.intent('intent2', (conv) => {
  const context1 = conv.contexts.get('context1');
  const contextParameters = context1.parameters;
  // ...
});

app.intent('intent3', (conv) => {
  conv.contexts.delete('context1');
  // ...
});
```

Here is my code...

```js
app.intent('ask_recipe_intent', (conv, {name}) => {
  const term = name.toLowerCase();
  const termRef = collectionRef.doc(term);
  //Set the context to store the parameter information
  const lifespan =5;
  const contextParameters = {
    name: name,
  };
  conv.contexts.set('name', 5, name);

  return termRef.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const {city, name, count} = snapshot.data();
      return termRef.update({count: count+1})
        .then(() => {
          conv.ask(`Here you go, ${name}, ${city}. ` +
            `do you want to check all the Ingredients needed?`);
        });
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log('error:', e);
      conv.close('Sorry, I did not catch you, can you say again or try another word.');
    });
});

app.intent('yes_list_ingredient_intent', conv => {
  const termRef = conv.contexts.get(name);
  const contextParameters = name.parameters;
  conv.ask(`The ingredients of ${name} includes ${ingredientall}. ` +
            `do you want to add to shopping list or go to steps of cooking?`);
});

app.intent('no_steps2cook_intent', conv => {
  conv.contexts.delete(name);
  conv.ask(`The steps to cook for ${name} as following ${stepsall}. ` +
            `enjoy cooking`);
});
```

But got "Webhook error (206) Malformed Response"

What's wrong with my code and where can I get more samples to learn except Temperature Converter Trivia which seems to be the older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several references to a variable `name` in your code, such as

```
const termRef = conv.contexts.get(name);
```

but nowhere do you define what `name` is.

When you set the context, you're setting it to the context that is literally named "name", but you're trying to set it with parameters that are stored in the `name` variable, and that isn't defined:

```
conv.contexts.set('name', 5, name);
```

I am guessing that the latter is supposed to be something like

```
conv.contexts.set('name', 5, contextParameters);
```

since you define `contextParameters`, but never use them. And that you mean to call your context "name" since thats the name you use for the name in that call.

Comment: Thanks for the instruction, also found Dialogflow has a guide for contexts https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services-actions-on-google#use_entities_and_contexts_in_fulfillment </br> Sorry, I should have read this before asking.